# cd in pipe after getting folder path

Tags: bash

When I run this command, I get the folder of where a local gem is installed:

e.g.

```
bundle show gem

/Users/user/projects/project/vendor/cache/gem-856752cd48f0
```

Can I use pipe to cd into this folder path?

e.g.

```
bundle show gem | ???
```

What would I replace the question marks with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cd` together with the output of the command:

```
cd "$(bundle show gem)"
```

If you want to pipe, you also make use of `xargs` like this:

```
bundle show gem | xargs cd
```

Comment: The latter is a no-op, unfortunately, since the `cd` happens in a subshell. :) (Unless the `lastpipe` bash option is set, which is not likely.)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd `bundle show gem`
```

it will execute whatever the code within the `` marks and pass the output as the input of the cd command.

Comment: Note that the `$()` is preferred over ``. See "The second form `COMMAND` is more or less obsolete for Bash, since it has some trouble with nesting ("inner" backticks need to be escaped) and escaping characters. Use $(COMMAND), it's also POSIX!" in [Command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

Comment: This doesn't work if the path contains spaces or other "special" characters.